# block time_stamp return value

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

When using `block_timestamp` to return value, why it's return `1,690,534,220,344` value? Someone please explain me what is the meaning of this value?

```
 #[ink(message)]
 pub fn abc(&self) -> u64 {
     self.env().block_timestamp()
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value **1,690,534,220,344** is a Unix timestamp when the block is produced.

If you are unaware of unix timestamp below is the definition.

The number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970, at 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Unix timestamps are commonly used to represent time in computer systems and blockchain platforms, providing a standardized way to express time-based events.